# Not able receive any inbound sms in twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-chat

I'm using python to create sms service using twilio . I've done with sms sending part but not able to receive reply back (inbound sms). How to fix this?

Using twilio api , but not able to see inbound sms in logs

Comment: Can you please explain what you've tried so far and where you are stuck now?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.